# Getting accelerometer input - Defold Engine

Tags: accelerometer, defold

I'm trying to use the accelerometer to move the character.

But with the use of action.acc_x / action.acc_y / action.acc_z inside `on_input()`, I can only get the information when there is also some other action being executed ("click", "left", "right")

I would like to change the script to only move the character with the movement of the device

```
function on_input(self, action_id, action)

    label.set_text("info#action", "action: ".. action_id)
    label.set_text("info#info", "info: ".. tostring(action.acc_x) ..", ".. tostring(action.acc_y) ..", "..tostring(action.acc_z))
    if action.acc_x > 0 then
        self.player_direction.x = 1
    elseif action.acc_x < 0 then
        self.player_direction.x = -1
    else
        self.player_direction.x = 0
    end
end
```

github: [game.script](https://github.com/guilhermebferreira/defold_swip_witch/blob/accelerometer/swip_witch/swip_witch/game.script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know Defold has only one situation when `action_id` is `nil` - it is when data received from the accelerometer.
That mean you can write:

```lua
function on_input(self, action_id, action)
  if not action_id then
    label.set_text("info#action", "action: ".. tostring(action_id))
   label.set_text("info#info", "info: ".. tostring(action.acc_x) ..", ".. tostring(action.acc_y) ..", "..tostring(action.acc_z))
    if action.acc_x > 0 then
      self.player_direction.x = 1
    elseif action.acc_x < 0 then
      self.player_direction.x = -1
    else
      self.player_direction.x = 0
    end
  end
end
```

Do not forgot to replace

> label.set_text("info#action", "action: "..action_id)

with

> label.set_text("info#action", "action: ".. tostring(action_id))